# how do i alter comments and comment form

Tags: 7, comments

I am trying to change the way comments are displayed in drupal 7 for a specific content type. I am using garland theme. Ideally I would like to modify comment display in my module as opposed to doing it in the theme.

I have successfully implemented hook_form_comment_form_alter to hide the author name this way:

```
function mymodule_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  //  krumo($form_id);                                                   
  switch($form_id) {
    case 'comment_node_mycontenttype_form':
      hide($form['author']);
      break;
  }
}
```

Now I would like to alter the comments to:

1. Hide the comment title link
2. Hide the "reply delete edit" links

I tried to implement `hook_comment_view_alter()` and `hook_node_alter()` but these seem not to get called. When I use the following code, nothing happens (no krumo outputs and no modifications).

```
function mymodule_comment_view_alter(&$build) {
  krumo($build);
}
```

```
function mymodule_node_alter(&$build) {
  krumo($build);
  hide($build['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-reply']);
}
```

The only way I found was to modify `garland_preprocess_comment()` in template.php in garland theme. But this applies to all content type and also I would like to have all my code in my module.

Is there a proper way to do this?

How come `hook_comment_view_alter()` and `hook_node_alter()` don't seem to get called?

Note I am using panels to add my content. So I have added the comments and the comment form using panels module. Therefore there is no field to toggle "allow comment title" as there is in structure->content type->comment settings. Even though the "allow comment title" field is unchecked, titles are still displayed. it seems like panels overrides this setting somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put this in my module I actually just did put the following code in my module:

```
function mymodule_preprocess_comment(&$vars) {
$vars['submitted'] = $vars['created'] . ' — ' . $vars['author'];
switch( $vars['node']->type )
 {
 case 'myContentType':
 $vars['title'] =FALSE;
 $vars['content']['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-reply'] = FALSE;
 $vars['content']['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-edit'] = FALSE;
 $vars['content']['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-delete'] = FALSE;
 break;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't say this is the "proper" way since technically you'd be modifying a core file, but normally the easiest way would be to create a custom file in your theme's directory called `comment.tpl.php` and make your modifications there. **But**, since you're using the Garland theme from core, which already has a `comment.tpl.php` file... Well, any changes you make to it will be overridden the next time you update to the next release of Drupal. Plus, **don't hack core**.

That said, assuming you were using a different theme, you could use Garland's `comment.tpl.php` file as a point of reference and applying some minor modifications like so:

Garland's `comment.tpl.php` file:

```
<?php
?>
<div class="<?php print $classes . ' ' . $zebra; ?>"<?php print $attributes; ?>>

  <div class="clearfix">

    <span class="submitted"><?php print $submitted ?></span>

  <?php if ($new): ?>
    <span class="new"><?php print drupal_ucfirst($new) ?></span>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php print $picture ?>

    <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
    <h3<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><?php print $title ?></h3>
    <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>

    <div class="content"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
      <?php hide($content['links']); print render($content); ?>
      <?php if ($signature): ?>
      <div class="clearfix">
        <div>—</div>
        <?php print $signature ?>
      </div>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
  </div>

  <?php print render($content['links']) ?>
</div>
```

Modified version for your theme:

```
<?php
?>
<div class="<?php print $classes . ' ' . $zebra; ?>"<?php print $attributes; ?>>

  <div class="clearfix">

    <span class="submitted"><?php print $submitted ?></span>

  <?php if ($new): ?>
    <span class="new"><?php print drupal_ucfirst($new) ?></span>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php print $picture ?>

    <div class="content"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
      <?php hide($content['links']); print render($content); ?>
      <?php if ($signature): ?>
      <div class="clearfix">
        <div>—</div>
        <?php print $signature ?>
      </div>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

After you make any such changes, remember to clear the cache so the changes are recognized by the system.

Comment: This works but I also need to make it specific to a content type. Not for all comments. Also I would like to make these alterations from inside my module.